# solr synonym searching phrase length issue

Tags: solr

I am facing a very unknown and unpopular issue of synonym length in solr. I have configured synonym at query time and not at index time and expand = false. My issue is with the size of phrase. I have configured synonym in following way for ex. "Marketing Technology,MarkSynonym,MarTech". but this is not providing me with the search results. I tried a lot and caught the issue(only If I am correct), I investigated that when the size of the leading word that is "Marketing Technology" exceeds 11 character(including whitespaces), then the synonym search stops working. So when I changed the configuration from "Marketing Technology,MarkSynonym,MarTech" to "Marketing T,MarkSynonym,MarTech" i.e. I changed the word "Marketing Technology" to "Marketing T" and its performing the search. Please suggest if there is any size issue with solr synonym searching. Also the above given is just an example. I tried using many phrases and came to the conclusion.

Thanks,
Lalit Joshi

Comment: i understand your meaning is solr synonym phrase's size to be limit ?

Comment: Yea @QinDongLiang, My issue is with the size limit of the synonym phrase . It just allows upto 11 characters. Any Suggestions or guesses? What can be the issue or how to over come this issue?

Comment: Where the document is explain 11 characters ?  solr official document ?

Comment: @QinDongLiang, First of all I thank you for your reply and the interest you have shown into my problem. There is no official solr document or any announcements for 11 characters. This is the issue I am facing in my solr synonym search configuration. Just want suggestions from people's regarding what the issue can be? Is this the configuration issue from my side or is there any limitation for solr synonym searching. And need resolution to over come this issue which I have mentioned and I think I am the only one who is facing this issue as I haven't read anything such any where esle.
Thanks,

Comment: i am sorry , these day is busy , no time to reply to you ,  you can configuration synonym's analyzer is keyword Analyzer, i guess it can solve your issue ,because it is white space Analyzer in default  .

Comment: Thanx @QinDongLiang again for your response. But the issue is resolved now. I found that the issue was with the stopwords configured. Actually, the synonyms configured were having some stop words in them and hence was causing the issue in synonym searching.